# How to initialize nested structs

Tags: c

I have this code in one file:

```
struct ReadyQueue {
    struct PCB *pcb;
    struct ReadyQueue *next;
};

extern struct CPU new_cpu;

typedef struct ReadyQueue *node;

node* head;

node createNode() {
    node temp;
    temp = (node)malloc(sizeof(struct ReadyQueue));

    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Error creating node");
        exit(0);
    }

    temp->next = NULL;
    free(temp);

    return temp;
}

node* head;

void addToReady(FILE *p) {

    node temp;
    temp = createNode();

    temp->pcb->PC = p;  // error here

    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
    }

}
```

Which creates a linked list of nodes. In my addToReady function, I am having trouble setting the PCB value which has another struct declared in another file:

```
struct PCB {
  FILE *PC;
};
```

I am having the error in `temp->pcb->PC=p` and its giving me a `Segmentation Fault 11` error.

Comment: mallocing the struct doesn't perform the malloc inside it. You need mallocs for members too

Comment: `free(temp); return temp;`? That means you return a dangling pointer

Comment: As an aside, please don't hide pointers behind typedefs.  It makes code harder to understand.

Comment: why not just `struct PCB pcb;` in your structure? why a pointer there?

Comment: checking if temp is NULL after dereferencing it isn't that useful too

Comment: `temp->pcb` does not point anywhere useful.